# How can I disable button from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to disable button when property 'Flag' is true. This is my model and controller.

```
public class User {

      public string Name { get; set; }
      public bool Flag{ get; set; }

    }
```

controller

```
public ViewResult Index() {

   var userFlag = context.Users.Where(u => u.Flag = true).FirstOrDefault();

   if (userFlag != false)
                {
                    // disable button 
                }
 else
                {
                   // enable button
                }

  return View();

}
```

Comment: @IrishChieftain: Hardly useful in an MVC project.

Comment: If you only get Users that their Flag is true, then how you will ever return a user with flag disabled ?

Comment: @OrelEraki: I'm also curious how the `userFlag` object in that code could ever be a `bool`...

Comment: @David, Indeed, the assignment in a Where clause looks weird my friend.

Answer (score 2):

You disable the button in the *view*, not in the controller.  First, the controller needs to send some information to the view.  Ideally this is in the form of a view model, but for now let's just put a simple value into the `ViewBag`.  Something like this:

```
ViewBag.UserFlag = userFlag;
return View();
```

Then in the view you can use that value.  For example:

```
@if(ViewBag.UserFlag == true)
{
    <button type="button" disabled>Click here</button>
}
else
{
    <button type="button">Click here</button>
}
```

Or however your button is "enabled" vs. "disabled" in your HTML.  You could even compress this into a single line using the ternary conditional operator if you want, it's a matter of personal preference.

But the point is that the controller simply provides the view with the data it needs to render the UI.  It's then the view's responsibility to respond to that data and render the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass that flag (boolean value) to the view and conditionally render the button with `disabled` attribute

You can pass the boolean value in multiple ways.

If you have a view model, set it's corresponding property. Let's say you have a view model called `YourViewModel` for your view and it has a `IsEnabled` property of boolean type ,set that in your action method and send the view model to the view.

So in your action method

```
var vm = new YourViewModel();
var user = context.Users.Where(u => u.Flag == true).FirstOrDefault();
vm.IsEnabled= user != null && user.Flag; 
// Pointless because you are getting the one with True;
// So the value will be always true if user is not null
return View(vm);
```

and the view, check the `IsEnabled` property of your model,

```
@model YourViewModel
@if (Model.IsEnabled)
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
else
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save"  disabled="disabled" />
}
```

**Or** if you do not have a view model/your view is not strongly typed to any class, you can pass the boolean value as the model of the page

```
var user = context.Users.Where(u => u.Flag = true).FirstOrDefault();
var flag= user != null && user.Flag; 
// Pointless because you are getting the one with True;
// So the value will be always true if user is not null
return View("Index",flag);
```

and in the view

```
@model bool
@if (Model)
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
else
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save"  disabled="disabled"/>
}
```

Another option is to use ViewBag to transfer this boolean flag from action method to view.

```
var user = context.Users.Where(u => u.Flag == true).FirstOrDefault();
ViewBag.IsEnabled = user != null && user.Flag;
// Pointless because you are getting the one with True;
// So the value will be always true if user is not null
return View();
```

and in the view

```
@if (ViewBag.IsEnabled !=null && ViewBag.IsEnabled)
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
else
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" disabled="disabled" />
}
```

Here i am rendering the enabled button only if the Flag value of your record is `true`. Adjust the code to negate it as needed ( in your question, it is the other way)

Answer (score 0):

You cas use `ViewBag` to pass flag value from controller to view as

```
public ViewResult Index() {    
   var userFlag = context.Users.Where(u => u.Flag = true).FirstOrDefault();
   ViewBag.UserFlag = userFlag == null ? true : false;
   return View();    
}
```

You can disable button in view as

```
 <input type="button" value="Save" @{ if (ViewBag.UserFlag == true){  @: disabled="disabled"} } />
```